# Use geom_smooth with transformed y

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to use `geom_smooth` when the `y` variable in the formula is transformed? For example:

```
#This works:
 myplot <- qplot(speed, dist, data=cars)
(myplot + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~log(x)))

#does not work
(myplot + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=log(y)~x))
```

What I am after is a line like this:

```
myplot + geom_line(aes(x=speed, y=exp(predict(lm(log(dist)~speed)))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fit a GLM for Gaussian (normally distributed) data and a log link. This will allow `stat_smooth` to use and return the appropriate predictions

```
(myplot + geom_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y~x,
                      family = gaussian(link = 'log')))
```

[image]

Comment: Syntax has been updated to `method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = 'log'))`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41189823/4241780