# Logarithmic y with geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is similar to this one: [Use geom_smooth with transformed y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138541/use-geom-smooth-with-transformed-y#)

In fact, it's the same one, it's just that the solution provided there no longer works.

What I want to do is plot a geom_smooth that has log(y) on the y side of the formula. If done directly in the `formula` argument, it gives a strange result. So, I will use the same example used in the question that I mentioned:

```
#This works:
 myplot <- qplot(speed, dist, data=cars)
(myplot + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~log(x)))

#does not work
(myplot + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=log(y)~x))

#no longer works:
(myplot + geom_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y~x,
                  family = gaussian(link = 'log')))
```

What I am after is a line like this:

```
myplot + geom_line(aes(x=speed, y=exp(predict(lm(log(dist)~speed)))))
```

Comment: are you still there OP?

Comment: If the built-in help pages are cumbersome to wade through http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/# has the latest info for ggplot2 and it's almost 100% necessary to hit that for anything but the most basic plots if you're upgrading from an older version these days. many major, brekaing API changes.

Comment: Hi, so I checked it, but couldn't find the right answer, because of the removal "family" argument. But I'll save the link here for future reference! Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you're right, it seems the necessary syntax has changed a bit:

```
(myplot + geom_smooth(method = "glm", formula = y~x,
                      method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = 'log'))))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! I could swear I had tried messing with the method.args argument, but couldn't figure it out properly. This is working now. Thanks man!

Comment: I was using method = "lm" instead of "glm". Gotta pay attention on that!

Comment: Why is it that the log link works, but not `formula = 'log(y) ~ log(x)'`?

Comment: @SebastianRivas and all the inappropriate upvoters: you should have asked another question.